# Solr 8.3 - Error getting replica locations : No node can satisfy the rules while add replica

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I'll try to add replica to existing collection, which has got about 200m docs, and size about 280GB.
I'll invoke `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=ADDREPLICA&collection=Collection3&shard=shard1&node=10.10.10.12:8983_solr`

And get error:

```
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":274},
  "Operation addreplica caused exception:":"org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.Assign$AssignmentException:org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.Assign$AssignmentException: Error getting replica locations :  No node can satisfy the rules \"[] More details from logs in node : 10.10.10.11:8983_solr, errorId : AutoScaling.error.diagnostics.3277099619256500\"",
  "exception":{
    "msg":"Error getting replica locations :  No node can satisfy the rules \"[] More details from logs in node : 10.10.10.11:8983_solr, errorId : AutoScaling.error.diagnostics.3277099619256500\"",
    "rspCode":-1},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"Error getting replica locations :  No node can satisfy the rules \"[] More details from logs in node : 10.10.10.11:8983_solr, errorId : AutoScaling.error.diagnostics.3277099619256500\"",
    "trace":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error getting replica locations :  No node can satisfy the rules \"[] More details from logs in node : 10.10.10.11:8983_solr, errorId : AutoScaling.error.diagnostics.3277099619256500\"\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrResponse.getException(SolrResponse.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.invokeAction(CollectionsHandler.java:291)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:247)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:214)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdmin(HttpSolrCall.java:837)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:801)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:546)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:415)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:345)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1596)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:590)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1300)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1215)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)\r\n",
    "code":500}}
```

I've try to change replica policy, but no result.

```
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":229},
  "Operation addreplica caused exception:":"org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.Assign$AssignmentException:org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.Assign$AssignmentException: Error getting replica locations :  No node can satisfy the rules \"[{replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection2}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection3}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection4}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection1}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection6}] More details from logs in node : 10.10.10.11:8983_solr, errorId : AutoScaling.error.diagnostics.3277628064970900\"",
  "exception":{
    "msg":"Error getting replica locations :  No node can satisfy the rules \"[{replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection2}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection3}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection4}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection1}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection6}] More details from logs in node : 10.10.10.11:8983_solr, errorId : AutoScaling.error.diagnostics.3277628064970900\"",
    "rspCode":-1},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"Error getting replica locations :  No node can satisfy the rules \"[{replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection2}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection3}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection4}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection1}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection6}] More details from logs in node : 10.10.10.11:8983_solr, errorId : AutoScaling.error.diagnostics.3277628064970900\"",
    "trace":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error getting replica locations :  No node can satisfy the rules \"[{replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection2}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection3}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection4}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection1}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection6}] More details from logs in node : 10.10.10.11:8983_solr, errorId : AutoScaling.error.diagnostics.3277628064970900\"\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrResponse.getException(SolrResponse.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.invokeAction(CollectionsHandler.java:291)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:247)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:214)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdmin(HttpSolrCall.java:837)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:801)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:546)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:415)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:345)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1596)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:590)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1300)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1215)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)\r\n",
    "code":500}}
```

Other collections work fine, and add replicas without problem. I've also created new collection with same configset as problematic collection, and it also add replica fine.

Logfile:

```
2021-01-18 09:29:57.877 INFO  (qtp1153907750-19) [   ] o.a.s.h.a.CollectionsHandler Invoked Collection Action :addreplica with params node=10.10.10.12:8983_solr&action=ADDREPLICA&collection=Collection3&shard=shard1 and sendToOCPQueue=true
2021-01-18 09:29:57.964 ERROR (OverseerThreadFactory-20-thread-5-processing-n:10.10.10.11:8983_solr) [c:Collection3 s:shard1  ] o.a.s.c.s.c.a.PolicyHelper errorId : AutoScaling.error.diagnostics.3277753693864300 {
  "sortedNodes":[{
      "node":"10.10.10.11:8983_solr",
      "isLive":true,
      "cores":5.0,
      "freedisk":116.462158203125,
      "totaldisk":399.98236083984375,
      "replicas":{
        "Collection2":{"shard1":[{
              "core_node1":{
                "core":"Collection2_shard1_replica_n1",
                "shard":"shard1",
                "collection":"Collection2",
                "node_name":"10.10.10.11:8983_solr",
                "type":"NRT",
                "leader":"true",
                "base_url":"http://10.10.10.11:8983/solr",
                "state":"active",
                "force_set_state":"false",
                "INDEX.sizeInGB":0.003988941200077534}}]},
        "Collection3":{"shard1":[{
              "core_node1":{
                "core":"Collection3_shard1_replica_n1",
                "shard":"shard1",
                "collection":"Collection3",
                "node_name":"10.10.10.11:8983_solr",
                "type":"NRT",
                "leader":"true",
                "base_url":"http://10.10.10.11:8983/solr",
                "state":"active",
                "force_set_state":"false",
                "INDEX.sizeInGB":280.61771321762353}}]},
        "Collection4":{"shard1":[{
              "core_node1":{
                "core":"Collection4_shard1_replica_n1",
                "shard":"shard1",
                "collection":"Collection4",
                "node_name":"10.10.10.11:8983_solr",
                "type":"NRT",
                "leader":"true",
                "base_url":"http://10.10.10.11:8983/solr",
                "state":"active",
                "force_set_state":"false",
                "INDEX.sizeInGB":3.959145396947861E-5}}]},
        "Collection1":{"shard1":[{
              "core_node1":{
                "core":"Collection1_shard1_replica_n1",
                "shard":"shard1",
                "collection":"Collection1",
                "node_name":"10.10.10.11:8983_solr",
                "type":"NRT",
                "leader":"true",
                "base_url":"http://10.10.10.11:8983/solr",
                "state":"active",
                "force_set_state":"false",
                "INDEX.sizeInGB":6.705522537231445E-8}}]},
        "Collection6":{"shard1":[{
              "core_node4":{
                "core":"Collection6_shard1_replica_n3",
                "shard":"shard1",
                "collection":"Collection6",
                "node_name":"10.10.10.11:8983_solr",
                "type":"NRT",
                "leader":"true",
                "base_url":"http://10.10.10.11:8983/solr",
                "state":"active",
                "force_set_state":"false",
                "INDEX.sizeInGB":1.966021955013275E-6}}]}}}
    ,{
      "node":"10.10.10.12:8983_solr",
      "isLive":true,
      "cores":3.0,
      "freedisk":398.34539794921875,
      "totaldisk":399.98236083984375,
      "replicas":{
        "Collection2":{"shard1":[{
              "core_node4":{
                "core":"Collection2_shard1_replica_n3",
                "shard":"shard1",
                "collection":"Collection2",
                "node_name":"10.10.10.12:8983_solr",
                "type":"NRT",
                "base_url":"http://10.10.10.12:8983/solr",
                "state":"active",
                "force_set_state":"false",
                "INDEX.sizeInGB":0.003988941200077534}}]},
        "Collection3":{"shard1":[]},
        "Collection4":{"shard1":[{
              "core_node4":{
                "core":"Collection4_shard1_replica_n3",
                "shard":"shard1",
                "collection":"Collection4",
                "node_name":"10.10.10.12:8983_solr",
                "type":"NRT",
                "base_url":"http://10.10.10.12:8983/solr",
                "state":"active",
                "force_set_state":"false",
                "INDEX.sizeInGB":3.959145396947861E-5}}]},
        "Collection6":{"shard1":[{
              "core_node2":{
                "core":"Collection6_shard1_replica_n1",
                "shard":"shard1",
                "collection":"Collection6",
                "node_name":"10.10.10.12:8983_solr",
                "type":"NRT",
                "base_url":"http://10.10.10.12:8983/solr",
                "state":"active",
                "force_set_state":"false",
                "INDEX.sizeInGB":1.966021955013275E-6}}]}}}],
  "liveNodes":["10.10.10.11:8983_solr",
    "10.10.10.12:8983_solr"],
  "violations":[],
  "config":{
    "cluster-preferences":[{
        "minimize":"cores",
        "precision":1}
      ,{
        "maximize":"freedisk"}],
    "cluster-policy":[{
        "replica":"<2",
        "shard":"#EACH",
        "node":"#ANY"}]}}
2021-01-18 09:29:57.965 ERROR (OverseerThreadFactory-20-thread-5-processing-n:10.10.10.11:8983_solr) [c:Collection3 s:shard1  ] o.a.s.c.a.c.OverseerCollectionMessageHandler Collection: Collection3 operation: addreplica failed:org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.Assign$AssignmentException: Error getting replica locations :  No node can satisfy the rules "[{replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection2}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection3}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection4}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection1}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection6}] More details from logs in node : 10.10.10.11:8983_solr, errorId : AutoScaling.error.diagnostics.3277753693864300"
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.Assign.getPositionsUsingPolicy(Assign.java:397)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.Assign$PolicyBasedAssignStrategy.assign(Assign.java:639)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.Assign.getNodesForNewReplicas(Assign.java:371)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.AddReplicaCmd.buildReplicaPositions(AddReplicaCmd.java:373)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.AddReplicaCmd.addReplica(AddReplicaCmd.java:159)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.AddReplicaCmd.call(AddReplicaCmd.java:93)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.processMessage(OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.java:264)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerTaskProcessor$Runner.run(OverseerTaskProcessor.java:517)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:  No node can satisfy the rules "[{replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection2}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection3}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection4}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection1}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection6}] More details from logs in node : 10.10.10.11:8983_solr, errorId : AutoScaling.error.diagnostics.3277753693864300"
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.cloud.autoscaling.PolicyHelper.getReplicaLocations(PolicyHelper.java:198)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.Assign.getPositionsUsingPolicy(Assign.java:385)
    ... 11 more
 
2021-01-18 09:29:57.978 INFO  (qtp1153907750-19) [c:Collection3   ] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/collections params={node=10.10.10.12:8983_solr&action=ADDREPLICA&collection=Collection3&shard=shard1} status=500 QTime=100
2021-01-18 09:29:57.979 ERROR (qtp1153907750-19) [c:Collection3   ] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error getting replica locations :  No node can satisfy the rules "[{replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection2}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection3}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection4}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection1}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#ANY, collection=Collection6}] More details from logs in node : 10.10.10.11:8983_solr, errorId : AutoScaling.error.diagnostics.3277753693864300"
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrResponse.getException(SolrResponse.java:65)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.invokeAction(CollectionsHandler.java:291)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:247)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:214)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdmin(HttpSolrCall.java:837)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:801)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:546)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:415)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
 
2021-01-18 09:29:59.902 INFO  (OverseerCollectionConfigSetProcessor-72272300412895235-10.10.10.11:8983_solr-n_0000000247) [   ] o.a.s.c.OverseerTaskQueue Response ZK path: /overseer/collection-queue-work/qnr-0000000142 doesn't exist. Requestor may have disconnected from ZooKeeper
```

Any ideas?

Comment: From a quick look the best guess would be the policy - replica=<2. 
I would suggest reading through documentation here https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/solrcloud-autoscaling-policy-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the node rule from ANY to EACH, with ANY it checks across all nodes

[{replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#EACH, collection=Collection2}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#EACH, collection=Collection3}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#EACH, collection=Collection4}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#EACH, collection=Collection1}, {replica=<2, shard=#EACH, node=#EACH, collection=Collection6}]